# How is $\|f\|_p \geq \bigg( \int_A |f|^p d \mu \bigg)^{1/p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

How is $\|f\|_p \geq \bigg( \int_A |f|^p d \mu \bigg)^{1/p}$?

This is presented as "trivial inequality". However since this is essentially the definition of $\|f\|_p$, then I don't see how $>$ is trivial?

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/lecture-notes/18125_lec17.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Because the set $A$ may be a subset of the "whole" space, say $\mathbb{R}$, where you define the $L^p$ norm, and the right-hand side of your inequality is
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|^p1_A\ d\mu\right)^{1/p}.
$$
But
$$
\|f\|_p=\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^p\ d\mu\bigg)^{1/p}.
$$

[Added: *On the other hand, note that it is trivially true that $|f|^p\ge |f|^p1_A$. But Lebesuge integrals have the property that $\int |f|\leq \int |g|$ if $|f|\le |g|$.*]

Consider for instance $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $A=[0,1]$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. In this case you have the strict inequality.

An even simpler example: let $f(x)=1_{[0,2]}(x)$ and $A=[0,1]$.

Comment: Good answer, but it is probably a good idea to stress that the crucial point is monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral and the fact that $|f|^p\ge1_A |f|^p$.

Comment: @MarsPlastic: Good comment :-) I have added a note.